# Recover a removed menu

Tags: pyqgis

I removed the "view" menu by mistake while coding in the python console using `removeAction()`. Now want to recover it  back. I tried commenting the code, didn't work. Is there any function to do it?

Comment: is it missing when you reopen QGIS?

Comment: I tried to remove view menu using `removeAction()`. It's removed. When reopening QGIS, view menu appears.

Answer (score 1):

Restarting QGIS is surely the simplest choice. Otherwise, you can always add it back:

```
# Remove the "View" menu from QGIS menuBar
iface.mainWindow().menuBar().removeAction(iface.viewMenu().menuAction())

# Add the view menu back. Note that it will then be the last menu in the menubar
iface.mainWindow().menuBar().addMenu(iface.viewMenu()

# Unless you add it with insertMenu
iface.mainWindow().menuBar().insertMenu(iface.layerMenu().menuAction(), iface.viewMenu())
```